# How to determine the limits of integration in computing marginal PDFs?

Tags: probability

Let $(X,Y)$ be a uniform bidimensional random variable over the region $$R := \{(x,y) \in R^2 : x^2 < y < x \text{ for all } x \in [0,1]\}.$$  Calculate the marginal PDFs $g(x)$ and $h(y)$.

I know how to get the joint PDF: $f(x,y) = 6$ for all $(x,y) \in R$.  I'm not sure how to get the limits of integration to get the marginals.  Still, realizing that $x^2 < x$ in the interval $[0,1]$, I computed

\begin{align}
g(x) &= \int_{x^2}^{x} 6\ dy\\
     &= 6(x - x^2)
\end{align}

The domain of $g(x)$ is $[0,1]$.  It looks like I was able to get by.  But now how can I determine the limits of the integral to get $h(y)$?

Comment: The region is bounded by $x^2 < y < x, 0 < x < 1$. You may try to rewrite as $x^2 < y, y < x \iff y < x, x < \sqrt{y} \iff y < x < \sqrt{y}$ and $0 < y < 1$

Comment: @BGM So I think you're saying isolate $y$.  So $y$ is my lower limit and $\sqrt{y}$ is my upper.  This makes sense because $0 < y < 1$.  That's the only interval where $y < \sqrt{y}.$  Got it.  Thanks!  (You should add this an answer.)

Comment: @BGM The reason you write $0 < y < 1$ is because $y = 0, 1$ are the points of intersection between $y = x$ and $y = x^2$?

Comment: The reasoning used here seems very similar to getting the limits of integration for double integrals over general regions.  But then having a sketch of the region is crucial for a beginner for telling which is the lower limit and which is the upper.